# How to move a cell in a table based on xml data?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, xml

I'm creating a tv anime guide in a table in html. I have an xml file with all the data such as name, start time, end time etc. I want the cell in the table to be placed in the right position in between the start and end times that the xml file data shows in the html table. How can I do this? The table only shows time such as 9am, 10am...but like the table below shows an episode could begin between 9.30 to 10.30. For instance, attack on titan begins at 9.30 and finishes at 10.30, and death note begins at 12pm and finishes at 1pm. I was thinking to some how do it by the id in the cell of the table but I'm clueless on how.

**How can I place a cell (anime programme) under a particular time just by getting the information from the xml file?**

See below for an example:

[image]

Here is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><anime_data>
<anime id="1">
<action_adventure_channel>
    <name>Attach on Titan</name>
    <start_time>09.30am</start_time>
    <end_time>10.30am</end_time>
</action_adventure_channel>
</anime>
<anime id="2">
<crime_drama_channel>
    <name>Death Note</name>
    <start_time>12.00pm</start_time>
    <end_time>1.00pm</end_time>
</crime_drama_channel>
</anime></anime_data>
```

Here is the HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html><head><title>Anime</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="anime.css">
</head>
<body>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th class = "table-main">Channel</th>
    <th class = "time" id ="9.00am">9AM</th>
    <th class = "time" id ="9.30am"></th>
    <th class = "time" id ="10.00am">10AM</th>
    <th class = "time" id ="10.30am"></th>
    <th class = "time" id ="11.00am">11AM</th>
    <th class = "time" id ="11.30am"></th>
    <th class = "time" id ="12.00pm">12PM</th>
    <th class = "time" id ="12.30pm"></th>
    <th class = "time" id ="1.00pm">1PM</th>

  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class = "table-main">Action/Adventure</td>
    <td>
    <?php
        $xml=simplexml_load_file("anime.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
        echo $xml->anime[0]->action_adventure_channel->name;        
    ?>


    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class = "table-main">Crime/Drama</td>
    <td>
    <?php
        $xml=simplexml_load_file("anime.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
        echo $xml->anime[1]->crime_drama_channel->name;     
    ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please post a fiddle OP?

Comment: Hi Kaal, this is several questions in one. Try breaking them down, tag them correctly, and show what you have tried. You will get much more attention and answers on SO.

Comment: its ok, im trying myself to do this. thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to use divs and spans.

```
<div>
    <span style="width: 100px;">action...</span>
    <span style="width:xxxx; margin-left:yyyyy;">attack on...</span>

</div>
```

Then you have to calculate the widht xxxx and the margin-left yyyy to show the element at the right position.

Comment: its ok, im trying myself to do this. thank you everyone!